# Composer error; mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/doctrine2-exporter

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php

https://github.com/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter
Following the guide above with composer, throws me an error:

> Root package 'mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter' >cannot require itself in its composer.json 
>   Did you accidentally name your root package after an external package?

I am installing mysql-workbench-schema-exporter and the exporter; doctrine2-exporter for the project. Thats all!

composer.json default

```
{
"name" : "mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter",
"type" : "library",
"description" : "MySQL Workbench Schema Exporter",
"keywords" : [
    "mysql",
    "mysql workbench",
    "database",
    "cli",
    "doctrine",
    "propel",
    "extjs",
    "zend",
    "sequelizejs"
],
"homepage" : "https://github.com/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter",
"license" : "MIT",
"authors" : [{
        "name" : "Johannes Mueller",
        "email" : "circus2@web.de",
        "role" : "Developer"
    }, {
        "name" : "Toha",
        "email" : "tohenk@yahoo.com",
        "role" : "Developer"
    }, {
        "name" : "Robert Vock",
        "email" : "robertvock82@gmail.com",
        "role" : "Developer"
    }
],
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.4.0",
    "doctrine/inflector" : "^1.0.0"
},
"bin" : [
    "bin/mysql-workbench-schema-export",
    "bin/update-sql-reserved-words"
],
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "MwbExporter\\" : "lib/"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter": "^3.0"
}
```

}

Comment: let's see your composer.json

Comment: why are you using mysql-workbench-schema-exporter's composer.json in your project?

Comment: @Federkun trying to convert .wmb to doctrine2 format.

Comment: remove _your_ composer.json, and install it with `composer require --dev mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/doctrine2-exporter`.

Comment: @FederKun This solved the problem. Thanks for help.